# Box2D: How to detect an object no longer collide with another object?

Tags: flash, box2d

Flash Box2D Question (But I guess the "flash" part doesn't matter)

Suppose there is an object A, which is the character
and an object B, which is the ground

Suppose the character can only walk when he touches the ground.

There is a box 2d contact listener, which I can detect when an object touches another objects, so I can use it to listen when the character touches the ground. But how do I know if the character has left the ground?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4):

> Suppose there is an object A, which is
>   the character and an object B, which
>   is the ground
>
> Suppose the character can only walk
>   when he touches the ground.

Assuming your object A is b2Body called objectA and
objectB is another b2Body called objectB and you world is called m_world. If objectB
is the ground I guess it has a density of 0 which makes it static.
If you want to check if objectA is above objectB you have two options, either through the bodies themselves which means using box2d unit measurements ( 1 meter = 30 pixels ) ,
either using the reference to your custom clips set through the userData property.

The advantage of using the second, I guess, is that you will be using the regular pixel units, bare in mind that you have your registration point in the center not at 0,0.

So,in your update loop( where you call m_world.Step ) you would have something like:

```
if((objectA.m_userData.y + objectA.m_userData.height*.5) < (objectB.m_userData.y-objectB.m_userData.height*.5)) trace('objectA is above ground');
else trace('objectB is on the ground');
```

Just read you comment and updated again.

I started writing a jsfl command for flash that gets the x,y,width, height from elements on stage and generated the box2d code. I used it to make this simple game:
http://www.disturbmedia.com/games/breakfast

It seems I don't need to reinvent the wheel as someone else already made something pretty consistent. Just got back from LFPUG where Carlos Ulloa talked a bit about box2d as well and he pointed to this thing:

http://www.sideroller.com/wck/

It seems to generate coordinate arrays for more complex shape definitions which is what you need. In a way this isn't the complete answer to your specific question, but it's a step forwared.

From your description, the game sounds really interesting. Keep us updated :)

Comment: the objects in my flash is always moving :p they are some life form which keep doing actions.. but I need to know whether they are on the ground or not. So isSleeping won't help in ground detection. Many thanks for your answer tho.

Comment: I have edited my answer according to your comment. Hope this helps.

Comment: @zifre I meant Box2DAS3. I don't know how it is in C++, plus this came handy when I got stared in Flash:

"The first one is Box2D measuring units that may seem weird until you realize Box2D works with meters where 1mt = 30 pixels."

quoted source is here:
http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2008/11/16/understanding-pixels-and-meters-with-box2d-and-how-to-select-an-object-with-mouse-part-1/

I hope I'm not wrong about the as3 version of Box2D because everything worked fine for me using this unit.

Comment: Box2D - all versions - lets you define what the ratio is in your code. The prewritten example files (such as helloworld.as) come with a setting of 1m=30px, and has given rise to the whole "1=30" myth. That said, most applications that use Box2D use 1=30. :)

Comment: @Andy I didn't know that. So you mean I could use 1m=1px and not need to do all those multiplications to 30 or 0.3333333333 ? That would be awesome.

Comment: what if the ground is not a rectangle? what if the avatar is not a rectangle? ;p  I'm looking for a Box2D method of
bodyA.isTouching(bodyB) or bodyA.isColliding(bodyB) ...

I believe Box2d has such kind of function internally?
It's troublesome to write my own polygon hit test for box2d, because a body can contain many different shapes, and probably my own test hit function won't be as cpu saving as box2d test hit function

Comment: Many thanks, I have to vote your answer up, but since I still need somebody to post the box2d "isTouching/isColliding" function.. so I don't wanna mark this question 'answered'. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Unreality No problem. It's annoying that I don't have the time to look into  it in depth right now. Glad I could help anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I think you were looking for this:

```
override public function EndContact(contact:b2Contact):void
        {
            if (contact.GetFixtureA().GetBody().GetUserData() != null)
            {
```

Answer (score 1):

In the contact listener , there is a method called Remove(b2ContactPoint) . This method is called by the physics engine two bodies are no longer touching. In other words, they have no contact points anymore . You can detect  at that point that the body A which is the actor is not floating.

Another cool solution will be to raycast from the Actor to the ground, check the distance between them and you can tell if you are floating or walking. Hope this works

Answer (score 1):

I solved this a while back, although my solution is goofy, it works really well. I just set the density, restitution, and friction of the ground to some "magic" numbers and in my contact listener I just check to see if one of those bodies has those numbers and that the other body is my sprite.

Like I said, it's goofy, but i have yet to see something else as easy that works.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure the box2d version has changed since you asked your question.

a common way to check ground collision currently is by checking the direction of the "normal" of the collision.

if it is upward, then go ahead and assume the hero is grounded, and allow walking.

to answer other parts of your question

there is BeginContact and EndContact.

i often store a var grounded:Boolean variable on my hero to keep track, and i even manually set it to false when jumping to try to avoid jump occurring more than once before the hero leaves the ground.

i hope this helps some.